# MCD con el algoritmo de euclides

Tags: python, funciones

He estado intentanto hacer una función para obtener el máximo común divisor entre dos números en python con el algoritmo de Euclides. Pero por algún motivo se me ha estado enciclando.

Gracias :)

```
def mcd(a, b):
  control=True
  n=0
  while (control == True):
    if (a == b):
      control=False
    n= abs(a-b)
    if (n > b):
      a=n
    else:
     b=n
  return a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Es una forma extraña de plantear la lógica en tu ejercicio.
El algoritmo de euclides plantea que
mcd(a,0) = a
mcd(a,b) = mcd(b, a mod b) , con a > b

Me parece que estas queriendo hacer el módulo por restas sucesivas, lo cual es correcto pero poco claro e ineficiente.

De forma iterativa, plantearía el problema así:

```
def mcd(a,b):
    a = abs(a)
    b = abs(b)
    if b > a:
        a, b = b,a
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a
```

Creo que es posible que seas nuevo en Python, así que una aclaración de sintaxis:

- a,b = b,a intercambia los valores de a y b.
- a%b devuelve el resto de la división entera entre a y b.
- while b itera el ciclo mientras b sea distinto de 0, ya que cualquier otro entero cae en True

Además, creo que esta es una buena oportunidad para mostrar un ejemplo recursivo, ya que es muy claro

```
def mcd(a,b):
    if a < 0:
        return mcd(-a,b)
    if b < 0:
        return mcd(a,-b)
    if b == 0:
        return a #CASO BASE
    return mcd(b, a%b)
```

Aquí según cada caso se llama de nuevo a la función con valores cambiados, a menos que estemos en el caso base (b = 0).
Por ejemplo,

```
# mcd(-2502,30) --- a < 0, cae en primera condición
# = mcd(2502,30) --- no cae en ninguna condición
# =mcd(30,2502 % 30) = mcd(30,12) --- no cae en ninguna condición
# =mcd(12, 30 % 12) = mcd(12,6) --- no cae en ninguna condición
# =mcd(6, 12%6) = mcd(6,0) --- b = 0, caso base
# = 6
```

Por lo tanto: mcd(-2502,30) = 6